# Can I upgrade nodes to chef 12.5.1 client in chef server 11.1.3 environment?

Tags: chef

We are running opensource chef-server 11.1.3 (we are testing chef-server-core 12.2.0-1).  Can I upgrade the client nodes in my 11.1.3 server environment to [chef-client 12.5.1](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/10/08/chef-client-12-5-released/)?

Would anything prohibit me from making use of the new custom resource model in my cookbooks?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a better question for https://discourse.chef.io/. From everything I can see, it would be compatible, but I have no factual basis for that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chef Client 12 and Chef Server 11 are cross compatible. This won't always be true of cross-major-version stuff (for example you won't be able to use some of the new Policyfile features, multiple keys per client, etc) but the core APIs haven't changed in an incompatible way since Chef Server 10 (0.10 at the time).